# How to swap Character of string with the given condition?

Tags: python, string, list, swap

```
def password(passlist):

    listt = []
    for i in range(0, len(passlist)):
        temp = passlist[i]

    for j in range(0, len(temp)/2):
        if((j+2)%2 == 0) :
                t = temp[j]
                temp.replace(temp[j], temp[j+2])
                temp.replace(temp[j+2], t)  
    listt.append(temp)
```

I am passing a list of string
example `["abcd", "bcad"]`. for each string `i` will swap `i`th character with `j` character if `(i+j)%2 == 0`.
My code is going out of the boundary of string.
Please suggest me a better approach to this problem

Comment: Strings are immutable, so temp.replace` will not work either.

Comment: How did you get pass through `for j in range(0, len(temp)/2):`? `len(temp)/2)` is of type `float`. And where is `if (i+j)%2 == 0` in your code?

Comment: At the end of the first loop there is one element in your temp! it isn't the correct way to do that

Comment: @Bazingaa only in Python3.  In Python2, `/` is integer division.

Comment: so you are just basically swapping every other item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
def password(passlist):
    def password_single(s):
        temp = list(s)

        for j in range(0, len(temp) // 2, 2):
            temp[j], temp[j+2] = temp[j+2], temp[j]

        return ''.join(temp)

    return [password_single(s) for s in passlist]

print(password(["abcd", "bcad"]))
```

- Define a function that operates on a single list element (`password_single`).  It's easier to develop and debug that way.  In this case, I made it an inner function but it doesn't have to be.
- Use three-argument `range` calls, since it's the same as doing the two-argument + `if(index%2 == 0)`
- Convert strings to lists, perform the swapping and convert back.
- Use a "swap" type operation instead of two `replace`s.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in python, therefore you cannot swap the characters in place. You have to build a new string.

Moreover, your code does not work for each string in `passlist`. You iterate through the string in `passlist` in the first `for` block, but then you use the `temp` variable outside that block. This means that the second `for` loop only iterates on the last string.

Now, a way to do what you want, might be:

```
for i in range(len(passlist)):
    pass_ = passlist[i]
    new_pass = [c for c in pass_] # convert the string in a list of chars
    for j in range(len(pass_) / 2):
        new_pass[j], new_pass[j+2] = new_pass[j+2], new_pass[j] # swap

    listt.append(''.join(new_pass)) # convert the list of chars back to string
```

Comment: Thanks for your help your code works fine for both even and odd length string

Comment: Can you please accept my answer then? It would be really appreciated